# Laravel: DOMPDF error when trying to get PDF

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I've been trying to get the PDF of a view using DOMPDF with a table full of ingredients populated from a database table.

I created a function in my Controller:

```
public function createPDF() {
      // retreive all records from db
      $data = Ingredients::all();

      // share data to view
      view()->share('ingredients', $data);
      $pdf = PDF::loadView('printableingredientslist', $data);

      // download PDF file with download method
      return $pdf->download('printableingredientslist.pdf');
    }
```

And the route in web.php is defined as:

```
Route::get('/printpreviewingredients/pdf', [MealPlanDisplayController::class, 'createPDF']);
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> fopen(D:\mealplan\storage\fonts//nunito_normal_46b9b3b48cc3ddbae60da82f1c1c5d29.ufm):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

It must be something to do with the '`printableingredientslist`' as when I replaced it with a `plain view page` with simple text that worked. I am struggling to see how there's a path issue however, as `printableingredientslist.blade.php` is simply under the views folder. What can the issue be? I am using `tailwind.css`, could that be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setOptions` method to use default font.For example like below

```
public function pdf() 
{ 
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('contact')->setOptions(['defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']); 
        
    return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf'); 
}
```

or

Create the directory `fonts` in `storage` directory

Ref: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/724

Ref:https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/176

Ref:https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/269